# How to centralize an object that contains many shapes according to its mass or area?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, corel-draw, balance

In my view, the usual center page alignment of most of objects that contains more that one shape make it look a bit unbalanced and unnatural.

For example, the first image below looks very bad, the second one is the usual alignment of the center screen of most software. As I said, the third one looks very natural to me because it is balanced according to the color area.

I wonder if there is any tools in CorelDraw or Adobe AI etc. that make it (area) mass-center align?

[image]

Comment: Hi.  How did you centre the one that you think looks natural to you?

Comment: By looking very carefully. First I center it by software, then shift it until it looks natural.

Comment: No toolset for this youd have to build the entire tool pipeline yourself

Comment: @C.F.G then you have found your tool already - your own eyes and brain. I'm not aware of any automated tool that can visually centre something.

Comment: @BillyKerr: Is there any tools in Corel or AI or any other design software that measure area of shapes? (I want to use this and do that manually)

Comment: Yeah, in illustrator the scripting layer has path length and area. You can also see it in the info documendt info window by adjusting what to see in the hamburger menu.

Comment: I don't think knowing the area of a shape will help you here. Visually adjusting the centre alignment of shapes depends on the shapes themselves, as well as their size, such as how off-centre they look, and how they interact or appear alongside other shapes, etc. I think there are too many variables here with regard to human perception to be able to work out something mathematically here, like some algorithm.

Comment: @BillyKerr: Consider [this image](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnVRJrnwsW4qJln2WYJtWGg96N1MLnA0S3ag&usqp=CAU). How it looks in your eye? what if we shift it a bit to right?

Comment: @BillyKerr: can you give some example about "depends on the shapes themselves, as well as their size"?

Comment: For that shape you would likely need to move it to the right slightly, and also downwards,. It's not only right-side heavy, but also top-heavy.  You need to learn to trust your eyes.  Remember we are all human and tend to see things like this in a similar way. Your judgement is as good as anybody else's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Illustrator, Inkscape, et. al., in general, won't "visually" center anything. They don't have the capability at this time.

Apps merely see the bounding area which contains the selected objects and then centers that bounding area.

The app isn't aware the right side of a selection may have more visual prominence than the left side of a selection. Apps merely see the outer boundaries.

So.. **No**. Apps won't center based on visual prominence. Such centering *must* be done manually.

---

There is a **script** for **illustrator** which purportedly calculates area:  https://gist.github.com/bryanbuchanan/11387501 
I haven't used this script personally and I make no endorsement, but it's worth a shot.

Chances are there are other similar scripts out there as well if one searches.

---

<sub>(Sidebar: Your "correct" image seems too low to me and needs to be bumped upward a bit - it's "sinking" basically.)</sub>

Comment: I dont know adobe does this to some extent to fonts. So it probably could do this. But Illustrator is a direct modeller so id expect to see this in indesign much much earlier than illustrator

Comment: Due to the start timing of Corel or AI on old computers, I draw them with MSPaint instead. I am agree with your "Sidebar".

Comment: I don't agree with your claim that "Apps won't center based on visual prominence". They can (but there is no tools yet for it). App can measure area of total object by math formulas and divide it in 2 then find the right point for centering.

Comment: @C.F.G -- Realize I posted they *can't*. And currently, for *design* software, that's true. I didn't post they **couldn't**. They certainly *could* if developers took the time to add such a tool. But as far as I'm aware, none of the more designer-oriented software packages will at this time. I'm *sure* if you moved to CAD or CNC tools (perhaps 3D as well) it's more of a possibility that software has the capability. -- I did edit and reworded a bit.

Comment: @Scott: You spoted what exactly I mean. So I want to ask, Is there any tools in Corel or AI or any other design software that measure the area of shapes?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of @C.F.G I don't know Corel at all really. My expertise is Illustrator. There's nothing in Illustrator to measure area... there *may* be a script out there somewhere for such a thing though - I'm uncertain.

Comment: Actually [**SEE HERE**](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-shape/td-p/1181381) for Illustrator. (Random Google search.) Note that the "secret programers object tree" was actually removed from Illustrator at some point, or hidden better. The shortcut detailed there may not work.

Answer (score 2):

Inkscape has extension which finds the center of mass of a single path (no group nor a selection of multiple shapes). If you find with it the common center of the mass of your cross and circle and move manually the parts so that the found center is in the middle of the rectangle or actually in the center of mass of the frame shape, the placements are the same that you seem to want in your written text.

The same extension measures also path lengths and areas.

To use that extension you must select the cross and circle and apply Path > Union. Then applying Extension > Visualize Path > Measure > Center of Mass inserts a plus sign to the center of mass as a separate item.

Group temporarily the plus sign to the union and move the group so that the plus sign is in the middle of the rectangle or actually at the center of the mass of your outermost frame shape.

I'm sure this amount of a work starts soon to feel wrong or at least unnecessary. If one is going to make reasonable good designs in reasonable time he must develop the confidence to place the items intuitively. In addition the center of mass -principle does not at all take into the account colors nor any other weight factors that people may use, perhaps unconsciously. An example:

In the next image the right side looks for me empty, no matter the center of mass of the united cross and circle is in the middle of the rectangle.

[image]

If you need some formal right placement rule it obviously must be much more complicated than the center of mass -idea above.

I would place the given cross-circle combination like this:

[image]

This assumes the cross-circle combination is fixed. If all three items could be moved freely or if I knew something of what the items present the selection probably would be different.

I can give no formal validity proof based on any generally accepted laws. If I were forced to give some explanation for my selection I would say that it's a subjective compromise between the center of mass rule and balancing the widths of the empty gaps in both sides.